# Nestjsx Crud library - cannot read properties of null (reading 'parsed')

Tags: javascript, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm having trouble setting up the Nestjsx Crud library on a brand-new project.
I followed the "Getting Started" steps defined in the library's docs [linked here](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#getting-started)

```
[Nest] 23136  - 08/24/2023, 11:07:03 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parsed')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parsed')
    at /Users/ilija/Documents/Projects/Private/crud-demo/node_modules/@nestjsx/crud-typeorm/src/typeorm-crud.service.ts:161:59
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at UsersService.createMany (/Users/ilija/Documents/Projects/Private/crud-demo/node_modules/@nestjsx/crud-typeorm/src/typeorm-crud.service.ts:161:8)
    at UsersController.createManyBase (/Users/ilija/Documents/Projects/Private/crud-demo/node_modules/@nestjsx/crud/src/crud/crud-routes.factory.ts:233:27)
    at /Users/ilija/Documents/Projects/Private/crud-demo/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Something similar seems to be detailed in these bug threads:
https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/443
https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/830

Is there a fix for this or has this project been abandoned in favour of the [dataui-nestjs-crud library](https://gid-oss.github.io/dataui-nestjs-crud/controllers/#install)?

Edit: It seems like the project's currently abandoned and the dataui fork works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/830#issuecomment-1975822993) and [here](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/825#issuecomment-1975814996).

My workaround is a patch of the current [@rewiko/crud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rewiko/crud) package. Use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to patch the @rewiko/crud package to handle the NestJS change.

For context, this is the cause of the issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/11450 (a constant `CUSTOM_ROUTE_AGRS_METADATA` was misspelt a while back and finally removed - the correct spelling is now used - `CUSTOM_ROUTE_ARGS_METADATA`).

Here is my patch:

[@rewiko+crud+5.1.12.patch](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/files/14477301/%40rewiko%2Bcrud%2B5.1.12.patch)